# Multiplayer game development with GWT

Tags: gwt

Can GWT be used for developing online multiplayer RPG type games?If so please provide me with the resources.If not inform me with other platforms to implement it.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have [PlayN](https://code.google.com/p/playn/), a cross-platform game abstraction library for writing games that compile to different platforms included gwt: https://developers.google.com/playn/overview

Its API includes everything needed for the game loop, graphics, physics, assets and network access (websocket).

I found [this](http://proppy-playn101.appspot.com/#1) presentation and [this](http://playn-2011.appspot.com/slides/index.html#16) one a good starting point (you have to push left/right arrows to change slides).

In their site, there are many [links](https://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/DemoLinks) to games developed with this library, included Angry-Birds

In summary, with PlayN you code your game in java using a common API. Your code will be compiled using either the gwt compiler to produce a HTML5 game, the java compiler to produce a java game, the android SDK to produce a native droid app, or monotouch for iOS. In fact you dont have to know so much of GWT to develop with PlayN, but your javascript game will benefit from GWT goodness.

[Edited]

Since you are using [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), a framework similar to PlayN, which delegates in GWT to produce the HTML-5 game as well, I would use the [libGDX-Net](http://cebrianbrothers.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/libgdx-net.html) extension since it would eventually work for multiple platforms, although right now it only is implemented for android and gwt. It uses gwt-ws for the websockets implementation in GWT.

A different option would be to use any comet library for gwt, I have success using [gwt-comet](https://github.com/rzschech/gwt-comet) and [gwt-atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-extensions/wiki/Atmosphere-GWT), I prefer the last one.

Comment: GWT wouldn't be a practical application for a game. GWT is good for focusing on business logic of a web application, but I also recommend PlayN for your game's logic. The front end (UI) of a GWT application converts into javascript, so you might as well just use JavaScript/jQuery unless you need the widgets and other complex logic you can write with GWT.

Comment: @Churro: I Disagree, although you need faster platform for certain games demanding a lot of resources, there are games suitable for running in the web platform using javascript like angry-birds. GWT is one of the best options to create good quality javascript. PlayN is focused on taking advantage of any HTML5 resource which improves the game experience. Adding jquery to a GWT app is a very bad idea. You can write everything with GWT even what jquery does (take a look to gwtquery). GWT compiler is able to eliminate death code, if you add an external library you lose that magic.

Comment: I meant to say use either GWT OR jQuery, but not both. I also didn't realize PlayN uses the GWT compiler to make HTML canvas games. So maybe it is not a bad idea. [I also found this Google IO video after further research.](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/kick-ass-game-programming-with-google-web-toolkit.html)

Comment: Yep, the alternative to GWT is to write js by hand, and jquery facilitates that. PlayN started with GWT and they extracted an API so as the code could compile to different platforms. Yeah, that Ray Cromwell's presentation was really good.

Comment: @Manolo Thank you
I used libgdx library for developing a small rpg kind game and used Gwt to deploy it on net and now I wanted to add networking ,but I don't know how to update positions of all players.What should I use?for it.The possible solutions I found on the net are websockets but I don't know how to embed them into gwt. Another option is to use a database but it is said to be very laggy. Can rpc mechanism in gwt be used for this.Please let me know.Thank you

Comment: Yeah, libgdx is pretty similar to PlayN. I think the best option for libgdx is to use [libgdx-net](http://cebrianbrothers.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/libgdx-net.html). Another option for GWT projects is GWT-Atmosphere.